# What are some examples of dayjs Localized Formats in action?

Tags: dayjs

I don't understand how [day.js Localized Formats](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format#localized-formats) works in action.

The day.js docs says this about Localized Formats:

> Because preferred formatting differs based on locale, there are a few
> localized format tokens that can be used based on its locale.

But then the example table underneath that just shows English formatting which is identical to what can already be achieved using the standard formatting.

The docs don't make it clear how things change based on different locales.

Can someone show me using examples?

Comment: I don't understand your question. City A in region B in country C uses a format for days. City D in region E in country F prefers a different format. A small village G located in an isolated region H in a small country I uses something really unusual that requires a localized format specific to them.

Comment: I get that different places use different date formats, what I don't understand is how it changes if I use the day.js Localized Formats plugin. There are no examples showing me how it might look in different locales so I have no idea what might change.

Comment: Have updated the question to make it more clear hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking, this file can used to see how things changed based on locale: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/tree/dev/src/locale

For example, `dayjs.format('L')` returns `October 27, 2023` in the default `en` locale, but `2023年10月27日` in the `ja` locale.